# Select Dimensions based on condition

Tags: tableau-api

My project has one requirement wherein I have to make a switch between Dimensions based on selections made in a Filter. 
The requirement is as below:

I have filters on `Category`, `Class` and `Sub-Class`, now if a user selects only one `Class` then the chart should show `Sub-Class` in rows and if user selects more than 1 `Class` then show `Class` in rows.

I tried to use `COUNTD`, `Window_Count`, `LOD (Fixed),` etc.

However when I am making the final selection of Dimensions, I am not able to do so. So, my calculated field which is `WINDOW_COUNT(count([Class]))` gives me the selection count – however when I try to use this in making a selection between dimensions `Class` or `Sub-Class`, I am struggling.

```
if WINDOW_COUNT(count([Class])) ==1 then [Sub Class] else [Class] END
```

This gives me `Cannot mix Aggregate and Non Aggregate Arguments` error

Comment: Pay attention to the error...its telling you whats wrong.

Comment: instead of `1` why don't you use `sum(1)`